# Can I use my old Canon Speedlite 277T with my new Canon dSLR?

Tags: canon, flash, compatibility

Actually it's my dad's flash that he bought many many moons ago to use with his old Canon T70. I don't have a flash but have borrowed his to try out, but he mentioned that some flashes will send too much voltage down to the camera and can damage the camera. That's the last thing I'd want to happen to my new baby (a 5D Mark II).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 277T should be fine, as referenced in [Photo Strobe Trigger Voltages](http://www.botzilla.com/photo/strobeVolts.html). If you're still not sure, you could always email Canon support to find out, but a quick Google check shows that it is being used on modern Canon dSLRs.

Comment: The trigger voltage list is really a great effort, but I'd take the information there very carefully, as I assume most of the people who provided the input don't know that their DMM **cannot** actually measure the voltage correctly. See my answer to this question earlier.

Comment: @ysap - I don't disagree, hence the mention of Canon support. However, in this particular case, comments on various Canon forums and other websites back up the assertion that this flash is fine.

Comment: Well, from my experience with the Sunpak flash, Canon were reluctant to confirm the Rebel XT is high V safe, and just advised me to use a safe-sync or else I will damage the camera. In this case, thought, the OP has a canon flash so they may be more willing to cooperate.

Comment: I'd guess that people measure with an oscillograph/-meter.

PS: Same as my answer, only with the correct link. Thank you, "community" for severely downvoting a obviously mis-pasted answer instead of silently deleting ...

Comment: @Leonidas - what do you mean by "same as my answer"?

Comment: I did post "If this is by any chance rather a "277T" it can be found with 4.8V (low enough) in this list here" ... and f'ed up the link. Simple as that :) Post has been deleted of course, rightfully too, I just wanted to bitch around that people can't or won't recognize a simple mistake and downvote before.

Comment: @Leonidas - I agree with you. A down vote with a note to the mistake that is then cleaned up (and then up voted) is the way to go about these things. However, it's a young community and learning such things is a part of it, so stick with it and contribute, good answers will be rewarded over time and the scales will balance.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone... i tried it and it worked fine.. seemed to overexpose in auto mode (could need some cleaning of the sensor), but playing around with manual settings i was able to get some good results.

Comment: So along those lines, a T6 should be ok as well?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, if it is an old flash, it is possible that the trigger voltage is around 200V. However, according to some information from Chuck Westfall (Canon USA official), all bodies since the EOS 20D should withstand this voltages (I don't have the link, but you can search Google and it will pop up in one of the many forums).

To be on the safe side, you can get yourself a safe-sync device that decouples the electrical contact between the flash and the body.

Anyway, if you want to be sure about the voltage, you can test with a multimeter. The problem is that most of them have a too-low input impedance so the reading is false. You need one with 10MOhm at least. I just got a cheap DMM from Walmart that was actually able to correctly measure the 190V on my old Sunpak flash, where 2 other meters failed and read around 6V. I **know** it should be 190V b/c it was confirmed by an industrial FLUKE meter and later on by Sunpak representative.

The Walmart one is from the Automotive shelf and named INNOVA EQUUS 3300. It specifically mentions 10 MegaOhm in big writings on the package.

This post may help: http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/read.asp?forum=1031&message=26638040.

Comment: [Here's](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/245292-REG/Wein_W990560_Safe_Sync_Hot_Shoe_to.html) a safe-sync device from B+H. If you trust your circuitry skills, you can also [build one yourself](http://olympus.dementia.org/Hardware/PDFs/FlashHighVoltTrig.pdf). I would highly recommend buying a commercially-made one; there's less chance of something going wrong and frying your camera.

Comment: most any proper DMM unless it is something EXTREMELY dodgy or old will meet the 10MOhm requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a 277T on your 5DmkII (the sync voltage was measured at 4.8V, and all Canon dSLR bodies made after the 300D have a sync voltage limit on the hotshoe of 250V), but obviously, you're not going to have e-TTL II, HSS, manual power control, or camera menu control over the flash. See [What features should one look for when selecting a flash?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17722) for descriptions of those features and why you might want them.

The 277T uses an external sensor (autothyristor) to regulate flash power, so you have to dial in the iso and aperture setting you're using on the camera onto the flash, and then shoot.

See also: [the 277T user manual](http://www.cameramanuals.org/flashes_meters/speedlite_277t.pdf).