# Why does the YN-565EX need a radio trigger with the YN-560-TX?

Tags: off-camera-flash, hotshoe-flash, wireless-triggers, wireless-flash, yongnuo

I am buying a Yongnuo YN-565EX TTL Flash Speedlite for Nikon. I am not sure what radio trigger do I need for this.

I have found the YN-560-TX transmitter on Amazon.

However, the description says the folowing:

> If you use it with other Yongnuo flash, like YN-560 II, YN-565EX,
>   YN-568EX ( Manual mode ), you need a transceiver of Yongnuo RF-602,
>   RF-603, RF-603 III.

I thought the receiver is built in with this flash. So why do I need a separate transceiver?

Answer (score 4):

Yongnuo only makes two types of flashes with built-in radio triggers: manual-only flashes (YN-560III & YN-560IV), and the Canon-RT compatible flash, the YN-600EX-RT.  **The YN-565EX/568EX/500EX (and MkIIs) models do not have a radio receiver built in.** (The [YN-685](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-yn685-speedlite-announced/) apparently has a YN-622/RF-603/RF-605 receiver in it).

The built-in slave modes on the YN-565EX are optical (light-based), not radio.  It can be used in Nikon's CLS (or Canon's wireless eTTL) system, and can be used as a "dumb" optical slave to fire from a flash burst from *any* flash (similar to SU-4 mode on a Nikon speedlight). Optical-based triggering, though, has range of line-of-sight requirements that become more stringent and restrictive if you're shooting outdoors and in bright sunlight.

The YN-560-TX transmitter is a "manual" trigger: it can only tell a flash when to fire, and it works with the YN-560III and YN-560IV speedlights, and the RF-602, RF-603, RF-603II, and RF-605 radio trigger units.  So, to trip a YN-565EX from a YN-560-TX, you need to add on a radio receiver unit.  *However,* the only control you have over the remote flash is firing it.  You cannot use iTTL, FP/HSS, or remotely control the power level/zoom of the flash.  The YN-560-TX can *only* control the power/zoom/group of the YN-560III and YN-560IV.

The YN-565EX/YN-568EX, however, can be used with i-TTL, FP, remote power, etc. etc. if you use a YN-622N transceiver as a receiver on the flash, and another YN-622N or the YN-622N-TX as the commander unit on the camera's hotshoe.

See also: [What are the Yongnuo flash naming conventions?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47702/what-are-the-yongnuo-flash-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 0):

1. There are 2 types of YN flashes, one with an integrated 2.4 GHhz receiver, and one without. Which one are you buying?
2. If you are buying the regular YN flash w/o integrated receiver, and you want to do radio-based, off-camera flash, then you will need some type of on-camera trigger, plus a some type of receiver attached to the off-camera flash. If you intend to have multiple off-camera flashes, that's where the YN Flash Controller comes in - place that on your camera, and you can control multiple flashes from the camera and won't have to walk around to the flashes to change their settings.
3. If you are buying the YN flash w/integrated receiver, same story as above, except you won't have to buy a receiver for the flash b/c it's already integrated. In this case, you just buy one single YN transmitter to place on the camera to fire the single off-camera flash, or you can buy the Flash Controller that will fire the one YN flash, and allow you control of other additional YN flashes if you buy more flashes in the future.

Comment: The YN565EX has an *optical* receiver that is compatible with Nikon's CLS. Even though it has an integrated receiver, it is not compatible with the YN560TX that uses *radio* signals.

Answer (score 0):

The receiver on the YN565EX is *optical*. It responds to pulsed light signals sent from the master flash mounted on the camera. This makes it compatible with Nikon's CLS, which is optical.

The transmitter on the YN560TX uses *radio* signals, not *optical* pulses, to communicate with the flash. You need to attach a *radio* receiver to the YN565EX so that it can receive the *radio* signals from the YN560TX.