# How do I set up my Yongnuo RF-603II trigger and Yongnuo YN-568EX flash?

Tags: flash, yongnuo, triggers

I have a Nikon D5000 with one Yongnuo RF-603II trigger. How can I use my Yongnuo YN-568EX flash as an external flash? What settings do I use?

Comment: And http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56682/why-does-the-yn-565ex-need-a-radio-trigger-with-the-yn-560-tx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the RF-603II to trigger the flash as a transmitter, **return/sell the YN-568EX flash, and get a YN-685 or YN-560III or IV**, or if you want to use it as a receiver on the flash, buy a RF-603, RF-603II, RF-605, or YN-560-TX to act as the on-camera transmitter.

The *YN-568EX has no built-in radio receiver*. And to get a radio connection, you need both a transmitter and a receiver. The YN-568EX only has optical sensors in it to be used as a CLS slave in Nikon's proprietary wireless system (which requires a D7000 or above, or a commander flash unit on the hotshoe), or "dumb" optical triggers which can be set off by the D5000's pop-up flash (S1 = if the popup is in M mode; S2 = if the popup is in iTTL).

If you *do* get another RF-603II-compatible trigger to use as the on-camera transmitter, make sure that the YN-568EX is out of all the slave modes, and in M mode. The RF-603II is a manual-only trigger, so you can't use TTL/HSS, or remotely change the power on the flash from the camera.  If you want these features, you'll have to consider the YN-622N triggers, and upgrading your camera body to one that can do HSS (FP flash).

You need a flash with a built-in radio receiver that understands the RF-603II.  The two speedlight models I listed above both have this capability.  Otherwise, you have to add a radio receiver unit that speaks the same protocol as the RF-603II onto the foot of the YN-568EX.

See also:

- [Why does the YN-565EX need a radio trigger with the YN-560-TX?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56682/why-does-the-yn-565ex-need-a-radio-trigger-with-the-yn-560-tx)
- [What are the Yongnuo flash naming conventions?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47702/what-are-the-yongnuo-flash-naming-conventions)