# Yongnuo YN468-II: How can I turn off the beeps?

Tags: flash, yongnuo

I have a Yongnuo YN468-II and it beeps while the flash is focusing.

How do I turn them off?

Comment: Do you mean the YN468-II?

Comment: Yes, YN468-II, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to turn off the recycle beep on a YN-468 II. [The user manual](http://www.yongnuo.com.cn/usermanual/pdf/YN468-II-cn_en_user_manual.pdf) lists no such capability or function. I believe the recycle beep on/off capability was added in the YN5xx series flashes.

See also: [What are the Yongnuo flash naming conventions?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47702/)