# ETTL with YN-568 and YN-560. Plus, manual with other flash unit

Tags: off-camera-flash

I have a YN-560 iii, Vivitar series i, RF-600Tx, RF-602RX and a YN-568 on the way. Ideally, I would like to use YN-568 and YN-560 iii in ETTL and the Vivitar in manual.

Does anyone know if the following will work/have I put this together correctly? Purchase a YN-622N-TX and YN-622N. Use the YN-622N-TX on camera to control both YN flash units. YN-622N-TX controls YN-560 iii in ETTL and YN-622N as shoe for YN 568 again in ETTL. Lastly, will the YN-622N-TX fire the RF-602RX/Vivitar in manual or is another YN-622N required?

Comment: @mattdm That question (and top answer) is specific to the Nikon. The same Yongnuo models made for other systems (i.e. Canon's e-TTL) often behave differently because they are designed to mimic the speed lights produced by a camera maker for that camera maker's specific system.

Comment: What ETTL system are you using? Nikon (CLS or i-TTL), Canon (e-TTL/optical or e-TTL/radio), or another?

Comment: @MichaelClark I assume this is Nikon too, because of the N in the models given.

Answer (score 1):

You will never have TTL or remote power control from a YN-622 with the YN-560III. The YN-560III is a manual-only flash.  Note that there is only a single pin on the foot of the flash. This is for the "sync" (fire) signal. There are no other pins. And TTL/HSS/remote power control from the camera all happen on those other pins.  The only unit that can remotely control the power on the flash is the YN-560-TX. That's it.

[A YN-560-TX can tell a YN-622C-TX to fire](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-yn560-tx-to-yn-622c-compatibility-added/), but not really the other way around. Basically, the 602/603/605 system is not really compatible with the 622 system. Which is why Phottix is possibly a better path to building a mixed manual/TTL triggering system. :)

Secondly, no YN-622**N** unit can do **e**TTL for Canon. The N stands for "Nikon"--it will do iTTL for Nikon.  You need YN-622**C** units, if you want to control a for-Canon  YN-568EX's power/zoom, and TTL/HSS remotely from a Canon camera. [The YN-568EX is not brand-agnostic](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62373/are-yongnuo-flashes-interchangeable-between-dslrs-or-are-they-brand-specific), and you should get the version that matches your camera.

You can "stack" the RF-602TX on top of a YN-622C to "relay" the sync signal if you want, but it's simpler to get additional YN-622 units. You may also want to look at the [YN-685](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-yn685-speedlite-announced/), which is apparently similar to a YN-568EX, but with a built-in YN-622C receiver.