# Can a YN622C-TX control a YN560-IV's power/zoom?

Tags: hotshoe-flash, yongnuo

Can the YN-560IV be controlled from a YN-622C-TX? I mean being able to control power and zoom and triggering, all remotely, from a YN-622C-TX *without a separate 622 receiver*.

Background:

I have a set of 2pc YN-568EXII and 2pc YN-622CII and 1pc YN-622C-TX.

I am considering buying another flash unit. Since this one will be used only indoors, I don't care about HSS.

I find that YN-560IV is economical and perfect in specs for me.

I got curious because the YN-622CII has a 560 compatibility mode, to receive from the YN-560-TX. Can a YN-622C-TX also transmit to a YN560-IV?

**[Update]**

I knew this was in the back of my head somewhere. I remembered seeing this when I got 622-TX but forgot about it:

[image: 560 compatibility mode?]

This function is not documented in manual. This function is boolean (on/off)

When "on" is displayed as value, Most buttons have no effect, and remaining buttons (up/down/left/right) change the value to off.

When "on" is displayed, pressing test button causes no leds to blink on YN622C-II in 560-rx mode (I don't have 560 flash to test with anyway..)

I checked and my FW version was latest, so I will keep an eye on updates. Perhaps YN are slow cooking this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, it can't.**

Yongnuo has never really thought of their triggers as a system. The hacked-on 560 mode in the YN-622-TX is more of an afterthought. And while you'd assume that the 622 should have the capability of simple manual triggering of 560 flashes, it does not. This is why considering triggering systems/flashes from Phottix or Godox may make more sense than those from Yongnuo if you need TTL and manual flashes to work together in the same system, or plan to grow your lighting system over time.

Personally, I'd say ditch the YN-622s and go for the new [Godox X1-C](http://flashhavoc.com/godox-x1-c-ttl-triggers-for-canon-announced/) TTL triggers (their analog to the 622s), and get [a TT600](http://flashhavoc.com/godox-tt600-speedlite-released/) (Godox's analog to the YN-560IV, which has an X1 transceiver built in).  Or, consider sticking with Yongnuo's 622 system, and save up the pennies to get a YN-685 instead of the YN-560IV.  But this type of gear changes relentlessly, and this advice may be outdated in a short while.

Godox at this time, however, seems to have the edge, despite the newness (read: lots of firmware updates) of the X1 system, simply because they have TTL/manual triggers that interoperate at equivalent-to-Yongnuo prices, and not just speedlights and speedlights with battery packs, but also bare bulb and studio strobe options in [their triggering system](http://flashhavoc.com/godox-flash-system-overview/).

Of course, you can also go with Phottix, but higher pricetags go with their better reputation and industry buy-in (e.g., Sekonic makes a meter with an Odin transmitter in it).

---

Addendum:

**[Fn] 06 "560"** is how you set the 560-Rx mode on the TX for MkI YN-622s (i.e., let a YN-560-TX transmit to the 622-TX and fire the remote 622s). See [Clive Bolton's TOYUG](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B77OmmGIg0gMMzZFaDVlZ1VNTE0/view), page 63. It was added in firmware version 1.02, so that's probably why it isn't in the manual which (I assume) was printed only upon initial release of the 622-TX (which predates the MkII 622s) and hasn't been updated since. This is why we love Clive Bolton's TOYUG. :)

Comment: Thanks for the info. For now, I just need one extra flash, and I have built rest of it around 622, so I'll just extend that. I'll go for 565 or 568 for now. I just wanted to save on extra receiver, which is not possible, so ok.
Appreciate the advice about Godox. I don't foresee upgrading my lights soon, But I will revisit this page if I do.

Comment: @GPS The YN685 has a built-in 622 receiver. That might be cheaper than a 565 or 568 *plus* a 622C receiver. Just be sure to get the Canon version. A lot of retailers list the Canon version, which came out several months before the Nikon version, as the YN658. They list the Nikon version as the YN658 N.

Comment: @GPS, YN-685 is, however, noticeably bigger than the 565/568. Canon/Nikon versions are easy to tell apart, tho: Canon versions have silver lettering; Nikon have gold lettering. And you can also [check the feet](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62373).