# Does the YN-560TX model support the YN560 IV flash?

Tags: yongnuo

I purchased a YN560TX a few months ago, today I purchased a YN560 IV. Upon reading the product description I noticed something that was never a problem before: Missing Yn560 IV compatibility.

Can someone confirm if this is a real problem or is it **assumed** to work with the YN 560 IV?

[eBay Link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Yongnuo-YN-560-TX-Manual-Flash-Transmitter-Controller-for-Nikon-flash-camera/231791033937?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D37115%26meid%3Df2c536da774244c1bbf7b947ada8cefe%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D291641631924)- Do let me know if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The YN-560TX was released *before* the YN-560IV, so any descriptions from that time period wouldn't mention the YN-560IV. They work together from multiple reports around the web [like B&H reviews](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1108992-REG/yongnuo_yn_560_tx_yn560_tx_manual_flash_controller.html). Also, be aware that the YN-560IV has been superseded by the [YN-660](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-yn660-speedlite-announced/).

See also: [What are the Yongnuo flash naming conventions?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47702)