# How to fire studio strobes with a Canon 580EX flash using Yongnuo transmitters?

Tags: canon, yongnuo, wireless-flash, monolights

How do I set up a shoot using my 580EX (Mark I) flash mounted on a Yongnuo transceiver on my Canon 5D Mark II and then fire 2 extra Hensel strobes with transceivers on them as well?  Does my 580EX need to be in manual or ETTL mode?

I find that my strobes only fire part of the time and not reliably every time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which Yongnuo transmitter is on your camera? Which Yongnuo transceivers are on your off camera flashes? Yongnuo has several different systems.

Comment: Also, "transmitter" may be misleading in your question. Yongnuo has both dedicated transmitter-only "-TX" units, as well as transceiver units that can be either a transmitter or receiver. Possibly see: [What are the Yongnuo flash naming conventions?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47702)

Comment: In addition, you may want to split up this question into multiple questions Right now, I'm seeing three separate questions: 1) how do I set up the triggers? 2) Does my 580EX need to be in manual/eTTL, and 3) why don't my flashes fire every time?

Comment: ...and lastly, is your flash a 580EX? Or a 580EX II?

Comment: does the flash work on cam itself?
Have you setup the right channel on all the yongnuo transmitters? (Every transmitter have to use the same channel. And this is often a reason for failture at beginning.) If the transmitters have groups, are the groups setup correctly? (is group enabled?) depending on the type of yongnuo transmitters there are versions for canon or nikon or other brands. you need the right one or it will not work with ttl. basically all hotshoe devices can fire manually with just contact to brackets and the middle contact.

Comment: The Yongnuo transmitters can be used as both transmitter and receiver, so I have the same device on my camera and on my flashes. I'm using Canon 580EX flash and sometimes a 430EX as well.

Answer (score 1):

The main issues might be how the studio strobes are set up with the transceivers you say you are using. The studio strobes also have an optical slave mode, so they should be out of that if you are using the radio triggers. And you probably also need to check that the transceivers are set on the same group as the on-camera transmitter, that all the batteries are good, and that the cables you are using to connect them to the Hensel strobes are good and have the correct connectors. I think you might need a 6.3mm to PC cable for each strobe.

The other possible issue is that you may not be waiting for the strobes to recycle completely between bursts. For example, a Hensel Integra 250 Plus takes 1.3s to recycle between full-power bursts (0.3s between minimum power bursts).

The on-camera 580EX, mounted on the passthrough shoe of the on-camera YN-622 can be in either TTL or M. On an RF-603/RF-603II/RF-605 transceiver, however it cannot be in TTL or HSS or anything other than M and all settings must be changed on the 580eX itself, as the hotshoe on the 60x transceivers is not full TTL passthrough, and can only communicate the sync (fire) and wakeup signals.  The 580EX should be set as an on-camera flash, not a wireless slave in Canon's optical system.