# Can several YONGNUO YN560Tx Flash controllers trigger the same flash units?

Tags: flash, off-camera-flash, yongnuo, wireless-triggers

I recently was at a Canon Experience weekend, to learn specifically about multi-flash setups. The demonstrator showed how he used three standard camera flash units, controlled by an equal amount of receiver units each. He then had two transmitter units, that the 'students' could try out on a model. Each of the transmitters was able to shoot all flash units.

I dont know any model/serial number/names of the devices that the demonstrator was using, and I am not really interested, other than the general way of how he worked.

I am looking to do a similar multi-flash setup, with the option that there may be two or more photographers working on one model. I looked at the YONGNUO YN560Tx Flash Transmitter with several YN560 flash units.

Question: Can **several** YN560Tx Flash Transmitters control/trigger the same/selected flash units? Is it possible to handout two or more YN560Tx Flash Transmitters to a group of people to use the same flash units around a model?

Comment: Im feeling dumb; after posting this question, Im reading about the YONGNUO YN-E3-RT, and I am now getting confused what the difference is between YN-E3-RT and YN560Tx ?

Comment: Maybe ask about the transmitter differences in a separate question?

Comment: Could do. But its not (yet) my concern. Why don't you ask?

Comment: @FlorianMertens Because she already knows the difference.

Comment: @FlorianMertens maybe see: [What are the Yongnuo flash naming conventions?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47702/what-are-the-yongnuo-flash-naming-conventions).

Comment: @inkista In addition to your excellent suggested url, I asked about the transmitter separately: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/93823/what-is-the-difference-yn560tx-between-yn-e3-rt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The Yongnuo YN560-TX system has multiple channels and flash groups. If all of your multiple YN560-TX controllers are set to the same channel and groups as the YN560-TX compatible flashes in question, each controller will communicate with the flashes when it sends out a signal (typically at a shutter half or full press or when certain settings are changed or the "test" button is pressed).

If the flashes are set to channel 3 and flash one is set to group 1, flash two is set to group 2, and flash three is set to group 3 then setting each of the YN560-TX units to channel 3 will let you control flash one via the group 1 settings, flash two via the group 2 settings, and so on.

The nice thing is that if multiple photographers are in the same space and each is using their own copies of the same models, as long as each photographer has their controllers and flashes set to different channels they can operate totally independent of each other. This is in contrast to the *optical* control system used by Canon's and Nikon's traditional wireless flash system. In the optical system two photographers shooting the same brand would interfere with each others' flashes.

Comment: Thank you. This confirms what I thought, but wasn't sure.