# What do you need to know before buying a flash for a dSLR?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, flash, hotshoe-flash, canon-700d

I am a beginner photographer who owns a Canon 700D (upgraded over my 1200D), planning to learn flash photography. Honestly, I am not a fan of using flash till now, but it seems for indoor shooting, flash is kind of necessary in low light. Can someone explain to me what I should be looking at when buying a flash? As a beginner I did some research and found that Yongnuo has some pretty budget-friendly flashes on the market. But I'm not sure what features to look for.

My primary requirements are portraits and indoor functions photography.

Comment: Check out: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17722/what-features-should-one-look-for-when-selecting-a-flash?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you need to understand is it going to be a fully manual flash or TTL (through-the-lens (TTL) metering) flash.